# Infopath calculated value "to show the week number based on SubmitDate"

Tags: infopath

I would like to seek some help on how to effect the below results, using infopath "calculated value".  Based from the "SubmitDate" field, the infopath "calculated field" should provide the week number of "SubmitDate" it falls under...where Week 1 starts 01 January, and week days starts Sunday-Thursday

example

SubmitDate  WeekNo (calculated value)
01/01/2020   Week 1
05/01/2020   Week 2
09/01/2020   Week 2

System:
Infopath 2013
SharePoint 2013

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, You need to calculate `FirstDayOfSubmitYear` from `SubmitDate`: `concat(substring-before(SubmitDate, "-"), "-01-01")`
Then calculate `NumberOfDaysBetweenFirstDayAndSubmitDate`: `concat(substring-before(., ";") + substring-after(., ";") * ((translate(xdDate:AddDays(../my:startDate, substring-before(., ";")), "-", "") < translate(../my:endDate, "-", "")) * 2 – 1), ";", substring-after(., ";") div 2)`
Then finally divide that number of days by 7 and round to the nearest integer: `round(NumberOfDaysBetweenFirstDayAndSubmitDate / 7)`

Comment: thank you for your help.  Being very new to this, i am having some difficulty combining the calculations (formula) you've provided in infopath calculated field, and throws an error when "verify formula".